# At the beginning of a race, when do you hold A for the initial boost?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I know it's something with when "2" is visible, but is there an optimal time? It looks like there's different degrees of the speed boost.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are 2 levels of boost. If you are driving a kart, you can tell which one you get by how many of your exhausts spit fire. If both spit fire, then you've got the maximum boost. If you are driving a bike, then your bike will do a wheelie when you get the maximum boost.

If you watch the numbers come on the screen it goes 3 - 2 - 1. The numbers kind of drop in from the top. You need to hit the button just as the number 2 gets to the bottom of it's downwards animation. It takes a bit of practice but after a while it becomes second nature.

Another tip is to count it down in your head - then you get the timing just right naturally!

Comment: The exhausts signifying it is genius!

Comment: "both" exhausts is incorrect, because not all karts have exactly 2 of them. More correct would be to track how long the boost lasts.

Comment: indeed - this game is full of little things like that. attention to detail is immense fair doos

Comment: @Toomai okay fair point

Comment: One of my coworkers brought up a good point: Exhausts are only on carts, on bikes you do a wheelie if you get the second level boost.

Comment: Great GIF found on this article: http://kotaku.com/how-to-get-a-perfect-starting-boost-in-mario-kart-8-1599227060